# how to update shared core data store between apps?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

### My Usecase:

For an automatic export running once in a while I build an HelperApp, while the configuration of still is made in the MainApp.

### My Setup:

- MainApp (writes data)
- HelperApp (mostly reads data but also writes to very few fields)
- both Apps share a single core data persistent store using the same myapp.storedata file in a Group Contrainer
- both Apps observe `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` tell each other through `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` when their context got saved

  - this works, so the other App knows when it should update it's persistent store / managed object context
- both Apps are sandboxed

### My Problem:

I can not pass `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` to the other app through `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`

How can I either

- Cause the core data stack of any app to reload it's data?

or

- Merge changes from the other app so that MOC gets updated?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm wondering EXACTLY the same thing.  mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: isn't possible without a notification object, and it's not clear how to update from disk.

Comment: This indicates it's impossible:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054180/nsmanagedobjectcontext-and-nsarraycontroller-reset-refresh-problem

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. Unf. I did not came ton a solution. Since it was for a small side project, I did just not pursue it anymore so far. But finding a solution on this would enable me to continue and probably even finish developing my small app. So I am interested in our take on this. I might consider using NSCoding instead of Core Data.